# Fraction simplifying algorithm, floating point exception error

Tags: c++

I am a beginner, and i am working on a C++ program that simlifies fractions, however I am getting this weird statement printed, it does not indicate an error, but it gives me the output "Floating point exception: 8".

Here is a snippet of my code(not yet complete), I do not ask for code and would prefer if my homework is not done for me, but I welcome logical suggestions to fix or improve the algorithms.

```
void Fraction::simplify()
{
  int i, x = 0, a[100], b[100];
  for (i = 0; i <= den; i++)
  {
    x = num % i;
    if (x == 0)
    {
      b[i] = i;  
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You have included no code?

Comment: This can't be the code that's generating the error, since there's no floating point in it.

Comment: Its there now, have to get in the habit of proper identation.

Comment: It must be, because When i commented out the function calls in the main program, it ran with no problems.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Invalid integer arithmetic, in particular division by zero, can also cause a (somewhat misnamed) floating point exception.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I'm careful never to divide by zero, so I guess I'm not familiar with the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x = num % i;`

Computes the remaining of dividing `num` by `i`

But `i = 0` in the first step, and you cannot devide by zero.

Comment: Thank you sir! do you think this is a valid algorithm to go on with? I have rolled my eyes over some code from peers, and it seems a lot simpler.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I din't fully understand what you code does.. I simplified fractions before but computing the greatest common factor, I found it simpler than dividing until the end.

Comment: btw, your code can be optimizing by ignoring common factors, I mean, if the number is not a multiple of 2, then is not a multiple of 4,6,..

Comment: The point of my code is to store all the devisable numbers into 2 arrays, one for denominator, one for numerator, than compare those two arrays and find the highest number that exists in those 2 arrays.

Comment: I thought about what you said, and realized that since you have round numbers such as 7,11,13,19 etc, it is better to make one algorithm that takes everything into account

Comment: BTW i should say my aim is not to point you wrong, simply tell you my logic, and see if there are flaws in it.

Comment: oh, don't worry, my performance recommendation is unimplementable. But you are trying to find the greatest common factor the hard way: take a look to Euclid's algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Using_Euclid.27s_algorithm